# Premake5-generated xcode project does not see vcpkg-installed dependency

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake, vcpkg, premake

### Problem

src/main.cpp with "file not found" issue:

```
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h" //File not found

int main(int, char**) {
    spdlog::info("Welcome to spdlog!");
    return 0;
}
```

### Background

I’m using vcpkg to install, say spdlog. I've put vcpkg as a submodule into `vendor/packages` using `git submodule add -f https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git ./vendor/packages`. Next, I bootstrap vcpkg, `./vendor/packages/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh`. Now I'm able to add spdlog as a dependency by editing vcpkg.json. I then install the dependencies `./vendor/packages/vcpkg install --x-install-root=vendor/vcpkg-installed`.

Finally, I make an xcode project `./vendor/bin/premake/premake5 xcode4`.
premake5 version is 5.0.0-dev

premake5.lua:

```
workspace "Vulkan2"
   configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
   architecture "ARM64"
   location "./"

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

project "Vulkan2"
   kind "ConsoleApp"
   language "C++"
   targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}/")
   objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}/")
   staticruntime "On"
   cppdialect "C++17"

   files { "%{wks.location}/src/**.h", "%{wks.location}/src/**.cpp"}

   includedirs{
    "%{wks.location}/vendor/vcpkg-installed/" .. "arm64-osx" .. "/include/",
    "%{wks.location}/vendor/vcpkg-installed/arm64-osx/include/spdlog/" --this may be overkill
   }
   externalincludedirs{
    "%{wks.location}/vendor/vcpkg-installed/" .. "arm64-osx" .. "/include/",
    "%{wks.location}/vendor/vcpkg-installed/arm64-osx/include/spdlog/"
   } 

   xcodebuildsettings = { ["ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS"] = "YES",
   ["HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS"] = { "%{wks.location}/vendor/vcpkg-installed/" .. "arm64-osx" .. "/include/" }
  }

   links {"spdlog"}

   filter "configurations:Debug"
      defines { "DEBUG" }
      symbols "On"
      libdirs {"%{wks.location}/vendor/vcpkg-installed/" .. "arm64-osx" .. "/debug/lib/"}

   filter "configurations:Release"
      defines { "NDEBUG" }
      optimize "On"
      libdirs {"%{wks.location}/vendor/vcpkg-installed/" .. "arm64-osx" .. "/lib/"}
```

Curiously, I was able to generate a xcode project (without issues) with `cmake` by making a CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Vulkan2)
find_package(spdlog CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(Vulkan2 src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Vulkan2 PRIVATE spdlog::spdlog)
```

Then, after installing dependencies with vcpkg, doing `./vendor/packages/vcpkg integrate install` and then `cmake -G Xcode -S . -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/erik/Dev/Projects/Vulkan2/vendor/packages/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`, as vcpkg recommended doing for cmake projects.

### Conclusion

So I'm looking to use premake5 to get a similarly working project as I had with cmake. Can premake5 generate projects without CMakeLists.txt? It would be great if I only had to list the dependencies in `links{}` and in vcpkg.json.

Is there an issue with my `premake5.lua`? Note that I have `libdirs` first appearing at the various configurations. Is that a problem for the `links{spdlog}` step?

Is there an equivalent way of specifying toolchain file with premake5, or does toolchain file not apply at all with premake5?

## Update

I noticed that the non-framework libraries in the `links{}` section do not appear in the project’s “Frameworks and Libraries”. Does it mean the links step failed? If I add the libraries (fmt, glfw3, spdlog and vulkan) manually to the xcode project‘s “Frameworks and Libraries”, I get this error:

```
Ld /Users/erik/Dev/Projects/Vulkan2/bin/Debug-macosx-ARM64/Vulkan2/Vulkan2 normal (in target 'Vulkan2' from project 'Vulkan2')
    cd /Users/erik/Dev/Projects/Vulkan2
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -Xlinker -reproducible -target arm64-apple-macos14.2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk -O0 -L/Users/erik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vulkan2-bjvzuhuwjwufmfaommqrpgnkatkb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug -L/Users/erik/Dev/Projects/Vulkan2/bin/Debug-macosx-ARM64/Vulkan2 -Lvendor/vcpkg-installed/arm64-osx/lib -L/Users/erik/Dev/Projects/Vulkan2/vendor/vcpkg-installed/arm64-osx/lib -F/Users/erik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vulkan2-bjvzuhuwjwufmfaommqrpgnkatkb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug -F/Users/erik/Dev/Projects/Vulkan2/bin/Debug-macosx-ARM64/Vulkan2 -filelist /Users/erik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vulkan2-bjvzuhuwjwufmfaommqrpgnkatkb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Vulkan2.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Vulkan2.LinkFileList -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/erik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vulkan2-bjvzuhuwjwufmfaommqrpgnkatkb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Vulkan2.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Vulkan2_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -lspdlog -lglwf3 -lvulkan -lfmt -lspdlog -lfmt -framework Cocoa -lvulkan -framework IOKit -lglfw3 -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/erik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vulkan2-bjvzuhuwjwufmfaommqrpgnkatkb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Vulkan2.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Vulkan2_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/erik/Dev/Projects/Vulkan2/bin/Debug-macosx-ARM64/Vulkan2/Vulkan2

ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lfmt', '-lspdlog', '-lvulkan'
ld: library 'glwf3' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: cmake is the next step. Cmake will generate the XCode project for you.

Comment: @sweenish Thanks, I’m new so I don’t quite understand what they mean under `Using vcpkg with CMake` https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started?platform=mac I’ve decided to use premake5 instead, can I transfer the information to cmake5?

Comment: Those cmake instructions are quite clear. I don't know premake so I can't speak to it.

Comment: Why would one want to use cmake outside of an IDE and what does this do? `cmake -B [build directory] -S . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[path to vcpkg]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`

Comment: I'm not going to teach you how to use cmake in the comments of this question. You have some reading to do. The vcpkg and spdlog documentation are probably good enough places to start.

Comment: After investigating further, I've updated the question.

Comment: I didn't have mac, but can you check in the generated xcode4 project than the paths are correct?

Comment: *"Note that I have `libdirs` first appearing at the various configurations. Is that a problem for the `links{spdlog}` step?"* No problems.

Comment: Not an issue, but `externalincludedirs` should be enough, `includedirs` is mostly for your files.

Comment: @Jarod42 I have premake5 version 6.0.0-dev. I was able to resolve the issue by going to xcode project properties -> Target -> General -> Frameworks and Libraries and manually adding the spdlog library there! 

However, is there a way for premake5 to automatically do this? It seems the `links {spdlog}` step did not work, since spdlog did not appear in “Frameworks and Libraries”? Incidentally, linking a framework such as `links{Cocoa.framework}` does indeed appear in “Frameworks and Libraries”.

Comment: @Jarod42 Correction: premake5 version 5.0.0-dev.

Comment: @Jarod42 I've updated the question and I'm pretty sure there's a linking problem.

Comment: See https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues/2176

Comment: From generation, `-lspdlog` appears in `OTHER_LDFLAGS`. Which is the exact error you got? (you might edit post instead of just answer in comment).